# UISearchDisplayController and UIAutomation

Tags: ui-automation, uisearchdisplaycontroller, ios-ui-automation

we're showing search results both in a table view and on a map in our app. The user can show a map over the search display controller by tapping on a button. The map is shown by simply moving the map subview to front so that it covers the table view.

When we attempt to write UIAutomation tests for whether the map view is visible, isVisible on the map view always evaluates to false, even though the map view is clearly visible and we can interact with it. If we never tap the search bar and type into it (table not shown) then the map view isVisible evaluates to true. It feels like UIAutomation just checks whether there is a UISearchDisplayController and assumes all other views are hidden by its table view.

Has anyone else experienced this? I've filed a radar as i believe it's a bug http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5890626432270336

Test project: http://s.swic.name/X1Su

Comment: Try using .logElement on the map to see if your reference to it is the same as what you think it is. If it does return an actual element consider using isValid/isEnabled instead. I'm not sure how the software determines visibility but I know that it sometimes is not very accurate.

Comment: Well our problem is that we can't .tap() items that happen to be "behind" the searchDisplayController. We don't really care if UIAutomation deems it visible or not.